# OAuth 2 - TokenExchange use cases

Tags: oauth-2.0, token-exchange

I have been reading about token exchange and each document talks about different use cases:

1. API gateway use case (https://tyk.io/blog/res-oauth2-token-exchange-rfc8693/) : Client Application gets an access token for API gateway and API gateway exchanges token to get new access token to access the actual resources.
2. This article (https://cloudentity.com/developers/basics/oauth-grant-types/token-exchange/) talks about exchanging an access token from third party OAuth server, to your OAuth server.
3. This article (https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-oauth-openid-connect-sdk/examples/oauth/token-exchange) talks about issuing an access to user A, which can acts as user B (Impersonation).

The RFC is not clear about the use cases. Can token exchange be implemented for all these use cases?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the Tyk blog post.

Both delegation and impersonation use-cases are described in the RFC.

In my post https://tyk.io/blog/res-oauth2-token-exchange-rfc8693/, the example I provided was about delegation. The Gateway such as Tyk, has it's own identity. The app delegates some of its rights to the Gateway. The Gateway is ***acting*** as an agent for the subject.

The RFC describes the distinction between impersonation and delegation https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8693#name-delegation-vs-impersonation. It introduces the concept of composite tokens.

A composite token contains information about both the actor and the subject - this is a delegation use-case.

```
  {
    "aud":"urn:example:cooperation-context",
    "iss":"https://as.example.com",
    "exp":1441913610,
    "scope":"status feed",
    "sub":"user@example.net",
    "act":
    {
      "sub":"admin@example.net"
    }
  }
```

In the impersonation use-case, it would be impossible to distinguish between the actor and the subject - the token claims are the same. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8693#name-token-exchange-response-2

```
  {
    "aud":"https://as.example.com",
    "iss":"https://original-issuer.example.net",
    "exp":1441910600,
    "nbf":1441909000,
    "sub":"bdc@example.net",
    "scope":"orders profile history"
  }
```

With regards to article 2, migrating between identity providers it not in my field of expertise. That said, I can't see why token exchange cannot also be used for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please comment on use case # 3? Is it a standard practice to use token exchange protocol to exchange token of one user (eg: service account) with token of another user (eg: admin)